# If I jump out of a catch-block with "goto", am I guaranteed that the exception-object will be free'ed?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, abi, setjmp

I have such code as follows

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch(InterruptException) {
  goto rewind_code;
}

if(0) {
rewind_code:
  longjmp(savepoint, 1);
}
```

My question is, is the exception object that is stored by the C++ runtime free'ed when I `goto` out of the catch block? Or is the runtime allowed to cache it until the surrounding function exists or something like that? I simply want to ensure that if I execute above code multiple times, each time taking the rewind code, I won't leak memory (because the `longjmp` won't execute cleanup code emitted by the compiler into or before function prologues).

Comment: Who else could've asked this question? :)

Comment: I know this is a theoretical exercise, but I can't resist posting the obligatory [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/292/) seeing the goto :-)

Comment: Any reasonable compiler should emit a `warning: what the heck are you doing?` when seeing this code. `:)`

Comment: I honestly hope this is a theoretical question...

Comment: @Korn errm. No it isn't. If you have a good idea on how to get rid of the `goto` that is equally simple, I'm all ears. Thanks for your generous insight!

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for not putting the try/catch block into a function and returning some code (say non zero) in the catch block ? You could then do `foo() && longjmp(savepoint, 1)` and forget about borderline and difficult to guarantee behavior.

Comment: Ummm, ouch. Mixing `throw/catch` and `longjmp` just seems to be asking for trouble. Big trouble. Trouble right here in River City kinds of trouble. `longjmp` is a C function; in a sense it is the C equivalent of `throw`. C has no requirements regarding how it treats C++, and C++ has no requirements on how `longjmp` performs.

Comment: @Johannes, if you would explain the reason for the code in the first place, maybe we could help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

§6.6/2:

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), destructors (12.4) are called for all constructed objects with automatic storage duration...

At least as I'd read it, "however accomplished" should/does include a `goto`.

Edit: Okay, based on Johannes's comment, what we care about is §15.1/4:

> When the last handler being executed for the
>   exception exits by any means other than throw; the temporary object is destroyed and the implementation
>   may deallocate the memory for the temporary object;

[ ... ]

> The destruction occurs immediately after the destruction of the object declared in the exception-declaration
>   in the handler.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm not asking about the copy of the exception object. I see that the parameter of the catch clause will be destructed. But I'm asking about the original exception object that is kept behind the scenes and most probably allocated on the heap. I.e the one that would be rethrown by `throw;`.

Comment: Ah thanks. I suspect that means I can be reasonably sure that the memory is free'ed.

Comment: oh, that bit looks familiar.  :D

Comment: @Johannes: Well, at least it means if it isn't freed, you have solid grounds for filing a bug report. This is a tricky enough area that I'm not sure being required by the standard *necessarily* translates into it actually happening (though the situation is certainly a lot better today than, say, 8 or 10 years ago).

Answer (score 4):

§ 15.1.4

> The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified
>   way, except as noted in 3.7.4.1. If a handler exits by rethrowing,
>   control is passed to another handler for the same exception. **The
>   exception object is destroyed after either the last remaining active
>   handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing**, or
>   the last object of type std::exception_ptr (18.8.5) that refers to the
>   exception object is destroyed, whichever is later. In the former case,
>   **the destruction occurs when the handler exits, immediately after the
>   destruction of the object declared in the exception-declaration in the
>   handler, if any.** In the latter case, the destruction occurs before the
>   destructor of std::exception_ptr returns. The implementation may then
>   deallocate the memory for the exception object; any such deallocation
>   is done in an unspecified way.