# Are objects created before setjmp destructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, setjmp

In [jpeglib](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/), one has to use setjmp/longjmp to implement custom error handling.

There are lots of resources where it is said that setjmp/longjmp do not play well with c++ (for example answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376085/476681) tell they do go along with RAII), but the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7262818/476681) say that the destructor is called.

I have this example (taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp) and modified a bit):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csetjmp>

std::jmp_buf jump_buffer;

struct A
{
    A(){std::cout<<"A()"<<std::endl;}
    ~A(){std::cout<<"~A()"<<std::endl;}
};

void a(int count) 
{
    std::cout << "a(" << count << ") called\n";
    std::longjmp(jump_buffer, count+1);  // setjump() will return count+1
}

int main()
{
    // is this object safely destroyed?
    A obj;

    int count = setjmp(jump_buffer);
    if (count != 9) {
        a(count);
    }
}
```

In this example, the destructor is called (as I expected), but is it the standard behaviour? Or is it compiler's extension, or simple UB?

---

The output:

```
A()
a(0) called
a(1) called
a(2) called
a(3) called
a(4) called
a(5) called
a(6) called
a(7) called
a(8) called
~A()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *can* be undefined behaviour depending on whether or not destructors would be called were an exception to execute the same transfer of control. In C++03. From section `18.7 Other runtime support`, `paragraph 4`:

> The function signature `longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val)` has more restricted behavior in this International Standard. If any automatic objects would be destroyed by a thrown exception transferring control to another (destination) point in the program, then a call to `longjmp(jbuf, val)` at the throw point that transfers control to the same (destination) point has undefined behavior.

There's similar language in c++11:

> The function signature `longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val)` has more restricted behavior in this International Standard. A `setjmp/longjmp` call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and `longjmp` by `catch` and `throw` would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any automatic objects.

However, there appear to be no destructors that are called in transition for this *particular* piece of code, so I believe it's safe.

---

Now, if you were to change the code to move the creation to *after* the `setjmp`, that becomes undefined behaviour. In my setup (gcc 4.4.5 under Debian), the following code (with everything else identical to your question):

```
int main() {
    int count = setjmp (jump_buffer);
    A obj;
    if (count != 4) a (count);
}
```

results in the output:

```
A()
a(0) called
A()
a(1) called
A()
a(2) called
A()
a(3) called
A()
~A()
```

and you can see the destructor is *not* being called as part of the jump although, being undefined, it may be on some systems.

---

The bottom line is, you shouldn't be jumping from region A to region B where the equivalent `throw/catch` would properly destruct an object, because there's no guarantee the `longjmp` will call the destructor.

Actually, there are some who would say you shouldn't use `setjmp/longjmp` in C++ *at all,* and I tend to lean that way myself. I have a hard time seeing a need for that even in C.

I think I used it *once* in my entire career (and that's a *long* career), to implement co-operative threading in Turbo C under MS-DOS. I can't think of one other time I've ever used it. Not to say there *aren't* any uses, but they'd be pretty rare.

Comment: But there are no automatic objects that would be destroyed by an exception in this case.

Comment: Yes, no exception is thrown.

Comment: @BЈовић, whether your particular environment works or not is _never_ the decider for UB. Sometimes UB works exactly as you would expect but it's still UB, and may work totally differently in someone else's environment (or during a blue moon, or with different compiler options and so on). For definitive information, the standard is always the controlling document.

Comment: I understand that if UB works in one environment, might not work in another. btw the object of type A is created on the stack (see the first line of the `main()`. No exception is thrown. Are these paragraphs still relevant?

Comment: Yes, they are relevant, but in the negative sense. If you put a `throw` where you currently have your `longjmp`, and a `catch` where you currently have `setjmp`, no destructors would be called. You'd only have an issue if you'd created `obj` somewhere between the `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: But that doesn't really answer the question. All the current standard says is what you quoted, and to see  ISO C 7.10.4, 7.8, 7.6, 7.12. So, by the current c++ standard, should the example destruct the object or not?

Comment: @BЈовић, no it should not, at least as part of the jump. It _will_ be destructed at the end of `main` when it goes out of scope. That's covered in the "normal" part of the standard dealing with local/block scope (3.3.2 of C++03, 3.3.3 of C++11).

Comment: Ok, that is what I was looking for. And generally, I agree with you on "don't use setjmp/longjmp", but I have to use them because the library is implemented that way. Thanks